# When using Google Maps in a responsive native map, rotation of the map is initialized

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I'm working on the ability to track the location with the user's location pinned in the center, and there are some issues.

When i rotate the screen and release my finger, the direction of the map is initialized to the direction in which the map was first created.

I want to fix this so that even if the user manipulates the map and rotates it, it does not return to its original position:

[image]

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        setCoords({latitude, longitude});
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
    );

    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        setCoords({latitude, longitude});

        if (mapRef.current && lastRegion) {
          const newRegion = {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: lastRegion.latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: lastRegion.longitudeDelta,
          };
          mapRef.current.animateToRegion(newRegion, 1000);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000,
        distanceFilter: 1,
      },
    );

    return () => {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
    };
  }, [lastRegion]);
```

The watchPosition method created a newRegion that tracks the user's location and updates the user's map based on what the user tracked. Annotating this part will make the rotation normal, but the map will not track the movement of the user marker, which will later disappear off the map. (And if this happens, I no longer find user's location.)

```js
const newRegion = {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: lastRegion.latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta: lastRegion.longitudeDelta,
          };
```

In my personal opinion, this is the problem. Whenever I update the location, I use this object to initialize the location, but the map rotation seems to be initialized because there is no map rotation value in this object.